# Override Spring data JPA id annotation.

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring-data-Jpa where I've an entity

```
@Entity(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

@javax.persistence.Id
private long dbId;

@Id
private final String id;

// others attributes removed
}
```

In above class I've two different ids **id** (marked with org.springframework.data.annotation.Id) and **dbId**(marked with javax.persistence.Id) , since my **id** field is always populated with a unique identifier (for Person class which I'm getting from somewhere else) so while using Spring JpaRepository it always tries to update the record and since it's not in db, nothing happens.

I've debug code and saw that it uses **SimpleKeyValueRepository** which gets the **id** field which is **id**, and thus it always gets a value and tries to update record, can I override this behavior to use **dbId** instead of **id** field? Is there any way to achieve same with some configuration or annotation, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each entity must have exactly one `@Id`. On the other hand, you might want to declare a column as `unique`. It can be done by:

```
@Entity(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private final String uuid;

    // others attributes removed
}
```

Also remember, that Spring Data JPA id should be reference `Long` instead of a primitive as you want to save objects with `id = null`.

`String id` should probably be `String uuid` and be initialized as `String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`

Similar situation would be an unique email requirement for user. On one hand it'll be a primary key, but on the other, you won't mark it as `@Id`.

If you need further clarification or your environment is more complicated, just ask in comments section below.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually I have a custom framework in place which expect annotation Id (from Spring data) to be present and I'm getting this entity from somewhere else which is to be put in hazel-cast and from there I need to persist in DB (using spring-data-hazelcast), now the problem is when Spring-data-jpa sees an Id populated with entity then it tries to update it which is not present in DB.

Comment: So you have to implement Persistable so you'll be able to save with an Id.

Comment: Can you please guide how to implement persist method with Spring data JPA

Comment: Just add a field `isNew` and override isNew method returning isNew. So you set isNew to true when it's a create, and false when update.

Comment: I know I'm asking too much from you, but can you please guide me which class method to override?

Comment: Although, I had different issue but the answer is perfect for the problem stated above, hence accepting answer